# Prime Checker function in javascript is only returning one prime number from an array containing multiple prime numbers

Tags: javascript

Here is the code I'm using to go through an array and pick out the prime numbers and push them to an empty array.  My problem is that when I node this, it's only returning the first prime number the code finds in the array regardless if there are more prime numbers in the array.  I can't spot what I might be missing...

```
 let primeXray = function(num) {
    if (num < 2)
        return false;

    for (i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if (num % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

let choosePrimes = function(nums) {
    let primeBlock = [];
    for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        let num = nums[i];
        if (primeXray(num)) {
            primeBlock.push(num);
        }
    }
    return primeBlock;
}




console.log(choosePrimes([36, 48, 9, 13, 19])); // [ 13, 19 ]
console.log(choosePrimes([5, 6, 4, 11, 2017])); // [ 5, 11, 2017 ]
```

Comment: copy & paste your code and the error. Don't use images for codes [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It would be best to copy your code into your question - **not** a picture - that way we can copy your code without having to retype it manually.  Anyway, your first block needs to be altered as you are using `return false` which will immediately exits the function.  You need to define a variable above the `for()` loop, set that to `true`.  Then the `if()` test should change it to `false` if required.  And, **after** the loop, return the variable **not** true or false.

Comment: I apologize for the jpeg.  I am new to using these forums.  I will remember to copy and paste my code from now on.

@ATD I see what you are saying.  Thank you so much.

Comment: No worries, I have edited your question to fix it.

Comment: Use "let i = 0" and "let i = 2" instead of "i = 0" and "i = 2" in the for loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you do not declare `i` with `let` or `var`, so it's created by JS and reused. Your `primeXray` changes `i` which disturbs the other `function`

```
let primeXray = function(num) {
    if (num < 2)
        return false;

    for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if (num % i === 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

let choosePrimes = function(nums) {
    let primeBlock = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        let num = nums[i];
        if (primeXray(num))
            primeBlock.push(num);
    }
    return primeBlock;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I just had this debate with a classmate.  I have been in the constant habit of initializing the index of the for loop with "let."  My classmate said it makes no difference and since it made the code cleaner and less to type, I feel for his shenanigans (or genuine ignorance) and started typing my for () loops without initializing them with "let."  Luckily that practice only started yesterday and it will stop now!!!  I really appreciate your insight.